# Validating azure ad access token

Tags: c#, .net, azure, validation, token

I am trying to validate an azure ad access token like here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-validate-azure-ad-token-using-console-application/

I keep getting the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' inside the tokenHandler.ValidateToken(...)

My code:

```
            string myTenant = "TENANT ID";
            var myAudience = "CLIENT ID";
            var myIssuer = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0", myTenant);
            var mySecret = "SECRET";
            var mySecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mySecret));
            var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration", myTenant);
            var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
            var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = myAudience,
                ValidIssuer = myIssuer,
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = mySecurityKey
            };

            var validatedToken = (SecurityToken)new JwtSecurityToken();

            // Throws an Exception as the token is invalid (expired, invalid-formatted, etc.)  
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
```

instead of TENANT ID I have the tenant ID from azure. Instead of CLIENT ID I have the client ID from azure and instead of SECRET I have the value of the client secret made in azure.

Comment: Is the token that you use still valid and has not expired?

Comment: Yes it was, it didn’t even came in the catch if I used the try and catch, it just crashed. I don’t know what I changed now and it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really didn’t changed the code but it works now. :)

Comment: Damn, followed the same page, would love to know what you "didn't remove" :\ 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74270706/c-sharp-unable-to-validate-azure-ad-token

Comment: Hmm, I really don’t remember what I changed. The code is exactly the same. Maybe that I changed the versions of the nuget packets to an older version.