# C# unable to validate azure AD token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I have a standalone blazor WASM app that needs to send requests to an external app. I need to validate the authentication that I receive from the WASM app in the API.

I can see the Bearer token being sent and I checked it up in jwt.io, the data seems to make sense.

The client configuration looks like so :

```
"AzureAd": {
   "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
   "ClientId": "****",
   "ValidateAuthority": true
}
```

I've tried the following TokenValidationParameters without success:

```
var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration");
var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();

var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
    ValidIssuer = config.Issuer,
    ValidateLifetime = false
};
```

I've loosened up the "Validate", hoping to find what's wrong, but I keep getting "Signature validation failed"

Any idea how I can validate the token?

Answer (score 1):

There're 2 methods to validate the token. The first is writing a custom filter to intercept all the incoming requests and as you know there's a bearer token in the request header, then you can use jwt decode library to decode the token and validate the claims.

But I still recommend following [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph/TodoListService) to protect your api via Azure AD directly. And here's a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration). You need to expose an API in Azure AD, then configure your app.

By the way, you've had the access token, I think you should have had your exposed api in AAD, so it mostly like that you only need to add authentication in your api project. Then In asp.net core web API project, you need to modify `Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

And appsetting.json

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "37xxxxxxxb2d7",
    "TenantId": "21xxxxxxd93",
    "Audience": "api://37xxxxxb2d7"
  },
```

Then in the controller, add `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: Hi! It is a multitenant app. It seems to be complicating things a lot since I keep going from tutorial to tutorial and it never seems to work, which I expect is because most of them are not made for multitenant. Does the appsetting configuration you provided works for a multitenant app too ?

Comment: multi-tenant aad app means it can be used in other tenant. for example, you can register an azure ad app in your own tenant and integrate it into your app, so that users( accounts like `xx@tenantA.onmicrosoft.com`) in your tenant can sign in your app. If it's a multi-tenant app, it can also be set into some other tenants like enterprise app, then users from other tenant can also use their account( accounts like `xx@tenantB.onmicrosoft.com` ) to sign in your app.

Comment: Yes, I want a public app/website where people can sign in with their email. But as soon as I start putting "common" the API doesn't authenticate anymore. I tried creating the default blazor wasm hosted template, creating new apps with VS in my azure AD. It works for my account but not for other people's email. I can't seem to make it work for everyone for the API

Comment: it should be the expected behavior.